# Codeigniter merge into one row record with sql one to many relationship

Tags: sql, codeigniter, one-to-many

I would like to query one to many relationship

eg:

```
Table A:                      Table B:

id | country_name             id  | name  | table_A_id

1  | Usa                      1  | kerry  | 1

2  | Australia                2  | jerry  | 1

                              3  | tommy  | 2

                              4  | cherry | 2
```

my purpose is to query the result to merge one row record

eg: result list:

```
1 Record           2 Record   
Usa                Australia
kerry              tommy
jeryy              cherry
```

Currently, I am using Codeignter framework and beginner for sql, please don't mind me guys.

```
$this->db->select('*')
>from("table A")
->join("table B", "table.A.id = table_A_id");
$query = $this->db->get();
if($query->num_rows() > 0) {      
     return $query->result();
}
```

My view

```
<?php foreach($posts as $post) {
   echo $post->country_name;
   echo $post->name;
} ?>
```

However, it gives me 4 row records.

```
1 Record           2 Record   
Usa                Usa
kerry              jerry

3 Record           4 Record   
Australia          Australia
tommy              cherry
```

Thanks you guys in advance for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you missed

```
$this->db->select('*')
>from("table A")
->join("table B", "table.A.id = table_A_id");
$query = $this->db->get();
if($query->num_rows() > 0) {      
     return $query->result();
}
```

it should have been

```
 ->join("table B", 'B.table_A_id=A.id');
```

hope this make sense

option B

```
$this->db->join('table B','B.table_A_id=A.id','INNER');
$query = $this->db->get('table A');
```

Comment: here is the error:::  



Not unique table/alias: 'pi_fmac'

SELECT * FROM (`pi_fmac`, `pi_fmac`) INNER JOIN `pi_fmac_person_bio` ON `pi_fmac`.`id` = `pi_fmac_person_bio`.`fmac_id`

Comment: `SELECT * FROM pi_fmac INNER JOIN pi_fmac_person_bio  ON pi_fmac.id = pi_fmac_person_bio.fmac_id` use this query

Comment: yes, but it results 4 records. you can see my question above again. anyways, thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

Try out this

```
SELECT country, group_concat(name) FROM city c INNER JOIN employee e 
ON c.id = e.city_id group by c.id
```

output

```
('USA '     , 'jerry  ,kerry'),
('Australia', 'cherry ,tommy');
```

Comment: i var_dump get those result, but I cannot pass it into view loop. can u show me

Answer (score 0):

My solution found without using inner join:

```
public function mergeRecord() {
    $array_store = array();
    foreach($this->one() as $row) {
       $child = $this->many($row['id']);
       if($child) {          
            $return = array_merge(array("parent" => $row), array("child" =>$child));               
            array_push($array_store, $return);                                              
       }   
    }
    return $array_store;                 
}

public function one() {
    $query = $this->db->select("*")
    ->get("table A")
    ->result_array();
    return $query;
}

public function many($id) {
    $query = $this->db->select("id, name")        
    ->where("table_A_id", $id)
    ->get("table B")
    ->result_array();
    return $query;
}
```